# pymongo: how to use $or operator to an column that is an array?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection like this:

```
user_id     albums
1           [1 2 3 4]
2           [3 5 7 8]
```

I want to find out all the records that, the albums contains 3 or 7 or 8, I wrote the code like this but not working:

```
or_array = []
or_array.append({"albums":3})
or_array.append({"albums":7})
or_array.append({"albums":8})

collection1.find({"$or":or_array})
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, looks like what you're doing [*should* work](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
collection1.find({'albums': {'$in': [3, 7, 8]}})
```

from the mongodb docs, `[IN] allow[s] you to specify an array of possible matches`

If that doesn't work, maybe back track and look at the actual types of `3` `7` and `8` in the collection to ensure they are ints.

```
print type(collection1.find_one()['albums'][0])
```

Comment: Curious to know if this works... and if it does, why doesn't the OP's method work?

Comment: my guess is it doesnt/shouldnt work (if the above didnt) but will probably lead him down the path to figure out why :) If it does i work, I'd love to know the diff as well!